# how to extend 5 parameter expression to 7 parameter expression in cron statement

Tags: apscheduler

```
sched.add_job(job_function, CronTrigger.from_crontab('0 0 1-15 may-aug *'))
```

The above expression is adding a five parameter cron expression, i have an expression like 0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *   which is seven parameter. how to use seven parameter in APScheduler?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use from_crontab()? Are you not able to use the cron trigger natively?

Comment: ```scheduler.add_job(job_function, CronTrigger(' 0 0 12 ? * 1 * '))``` but it is giving me error even for a valid cron expression - Unrecognized expression "0 0 12 ? * 1 *" for field "year"

Comment: Please go read the documentation because this is not how CronTrigger works.